# Understanding how the system calls pipe(), fork and dup work

Tags: c, shell

I am writing a shell in C that handles redirection operators and pipes. Is the following idea right for handling pipes?. So I create a pipe in the following manner:

```
  int pipefd[2];
  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        myshell_exit(-1);
    }
```

and then I fork a new process and in the new processI redirect the stdout to one of the ends of pipes like so:

```
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,pipefd[1]);
```

so the parent process can now read from the pipe and redirect the stdin to the end of the pipe that is for reading. Like so.

```
dup2(STDIN_FILENO,pipefd[0]);
```

and then I fork a new process, so the next command or program is executed having as input `pipefd[0]`

Example: cat file.txt | grep string

In conclusion, I fork two processes in the parent process. One for executing the current program and another one for the next program. The task is inductive.

Is this idea right?

Here is the code of the main function. Assume all the weird functions work.

```
int myshell_execute(struct processNode* list)
{
  int i;
  char* program = list->program;  // Get the program to be executed
  char ** program_args = list->program_arguments; // get the programs and arguments to be executed
  char ** redirection_string = list->redirection; //get the part of the command that contains redirection
  int *status;
  int* stdout;
  int stdout_num = 1;
  stdout = &stdout_num;
  int fileDescriptor;
  pid_t pid;
  struct processNode* next_node  = (*list).next; // next node to be handled



    if(strcmp(program,"cd") == 0)
    {
      return myshell_cd(program_args);
    }
    else if (strcmp(program,"exit") == 0)
    {
      return myshell_exit(0);
    }


  int pipefd[2];
  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        myshell_exit(-1);
    }


// Execute the current program
  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
  {  
    if(sizeOfLine(redirection_string) != 0)
    {
    redirectionHandler(redirection_string,stdout); // This works. This just handles redirection properly
    }

    if(*stdout == 1 && list->next !=NULL)
    {
       dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,pipefd[1]); // with this line of code, I intend to redirect the stdout to the file descriptor pipefd[1], so the next command can use it if there are pipes. The reason why I put it in an if is because 1) stdout may be handled by the function redirectionHandler, so we don't touch it or we are in the last node
    }
    if(execvp(program,program_args) !=-1)
    {
      perror("myshell:");
    }
     myshell_exit(-1);
  }
  else if (pid <0)
    {
      perror("myshell: ");
      myshell_exit(-1);
   }
  else
   {
     wait(status);
   }

  // Go to the next command to be executed
   if(list->next != NULL) // I parse the command line in a convenient mannner. Thar works too
   {
     dup2(STDIN_FILENO,pipefd[0]);

      pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0)
       {  
         return myshell_execute(next_node);
       }
      else if (pid <0)
      {
          perror("myshell: ");
          myshell_exit(-1);
      }
      else
      {
      wait(status);
      }

    }
   else
   {
     myshell_exit(0);
   }



}
```

All the commands that don't contain pipes are handled properly but the problem is when there are pipes to handle.

Comment: The general idea is correct. Parent and child process have same `stdout` and `stdin`. You redirect stdout of child process to on end of the pipe, and you redirect `stdin` of parent to the other end of the pipe. 
So whatever was being sent to `stdout` of child process will now be in pipe until parent process reads. Then after you fork another child process, it can receive its input from pipe.